# MBR or GPT for bootable USB for CentOS 8?

Tags: centos

Should I make MBR or GPT for bootable USB for the installation of centOS 8?

Does it depend on the partitioning type that my existing Windows is?

Will it make serious error during installation if the USB is wrong partitioning type?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with MBR as every PC will be able to boot it, whilst if you go with GPT only machines from say this decade will be able to boot it. If you are only planning on installing once on a machine that is not from the computing dark ages then you can ignore this as a consideration. If the USB drive is very large then MBR might not be able to address all of it. If you plan to reformat the USB after you have done the installation then you can change the partitioning at that time.

The partitioning of the USB does not depend on the partitioning of any other device such as your hard drive. The BIOS settings make need to be altered to make sure that it can find the USB in legacy mode before it finds the hard drive if you want it to boot automatically, but if you are asking the BIOS to give a list of drives and boot from one of them then this shouldn't matter. You may also need to disable `secure boot` in the BIOS.

If the USB boots then if it is MBR or GPT will make no difference to the installation.

Answer (score 0):

As it's just a USB for installation, either one is fine. The only reason that you'd actually need GPT is if the drive is larger than 2TB as MBR won't be able to address anything that's larger but I doubt that you're using a drive that big just for installation.

You can partition any of the other drives that will be used by CentOS 8 however you'd like with the condition of GPT being needed for drives larger than 2TB.